# Defining a "child" variables in "let"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have 2 models which I want to test: Article and User. User has_many articles. In one of the test cases I define a variable:

```
context 'some context' do
  let(:my_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

How do I create 100 articles belonging to that `my_user`? I tried this:

```
let(:my_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, articles: [build(:article)]) } # error

  # or
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: my_user) } # doesn't work
  it 'fdsfdsfs' do
    # my_user.articles still has no articles
  end
```

but it didn't pan out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it in the factory itself using callbacks or you can do it using `create_list` like so:

```
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:article) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:article, 100, user: user) }
```

I'm using `let!` here which might not be necessary but because you're not showing your entire test I can't be sure if everything is being lazy loaded.

To do it with callbacks, I like to do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@email.com" }
    password 'password'

    factory :user_with_articles do
      after(:create) do |user|
        create_list(:article, 100, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your test you can do

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_articles) }
```

This will create a user with 100 articles.

Comment: `let!(:article) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:article, 100) }` - I need not just to create 100 articles, but 100 articles belonging to the user created earlier.

Comment: Right, a simple miss on my part - added that to the code!

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the fine answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27756067/1008891, it appears that your first attempt failed because you tried to invoke `FactoryGirl.build` without qualifying the reference to `build` and your second attempt failed because `let(:article)` was lazily evaluated and you never referenced `article` in your test, resulting the article never getting associated with your user.